# How to remove objects from an array which match another array of ids

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got an array of id's.  I also have another array of objects. I would like to remove those objects which match with the array of id's. Below is the pseudo code for the same. Can someone help me with the best approch?

```js
const ids = ['1', '2'];

const objs = [
  {
  id: "1", 
  name : "one",
 },
 {
  id: "1", 
  name : "two"
},
{
  id: "3", 
  name : "three",
},
{
  id: "4", 
  name : "four"
},
];

ids.forEach(id => {
  const x =   objs.filter(obj =>  obj.id !== id )
  console.log('x ==', x);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `filter` and `includes` method

```js
const ids = ["1", "2"];

const objs = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "one",
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "two",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "three",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "four",
  },
];

const res = objs.filter(({ id }) => !ids.includes(id));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put the `ids` in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to iterate over the array of objects and [`.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) to check if the `id` is in this `set`:

```js
const ids = ['1', '2'];
const objs = [
  { id: "1", name : "one" },
  { id: "1", name : "two" },
  { id: "3", name : "three" },
  { id: "4", name : "four" },
];

const set = new Set(ids);
const arr = objs.filter(obj => !set.has(obj.id));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

1st requirement -> you have to check for all elements in id array
way to do that using array's built in method is array.includes() or indexof methods

2nd Requirement -> pick out elements not matching with ur 1st requirement which means filter the array.

Combile two

```
arr = arr.filter(x => !ids.includes(x.id))
```

Cool es6 destructung syntax

```
arr = arr.filter(({id}) => !ids.includes(id))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ids = ['1', '2'];
const objs = [
  {
  id: "1", 
  name : "one",
 },
 {
  id: "1", 
  name : "two"
},
{
  id: "3", 
  name : "three",
},
{
  id: "4", 
  name : "four"
},
];
let  arr = objs.filter(function(i){
      return ids.indexOf(i.id) === -1;
    });
console.log(arr)
```